# How to stop screen assets from moving when showing/hiding the navigation bar?

Tags: java, android

I am hiding the navigation bar (bottom of the screen on a tablet, showing the clock and navigation icons) in an activity of my app.

When the user touches the screen, the bar re-appears, and again if they touch it, it hides away again.

The problem is that when showing the bar, the whole of the app activity view moves up with it.

Ideally, I just want the bar to lay over the top of my activity view. Alternatively, I'd like to keep some assets (some buttons) "stuck" in place.

My app is using API 17 (I cannot move to the latest API).